# Getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, linked-list

I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next' when I am trying to reverse a linked list.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head):
        prev = None
        while head:
            curr = head
            head = head.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
        return prev

s = Solution()
s.reverseList([0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: You never initialized anything as a `ListNode` you only declared the class. I am assuming you want every value in `head` to be a `ListNode`?

Comment: you are passing a `List` to your `reverseList`, not a linked list.